# Generate a unique template instance for use of template

Tags: c++

Does anyone know if it's possible to generate a unique template instance (I think that's the word), for every use, even if the types are matching?

My thought was to use some type of compile time counter? Like

```
    constexpr int next_count() 
    {
        // what do I do here?
    }


    template 
    struct foo
    {
        ...
    };

    template 
    auto make_foo(T val)
    {
        return foo(val);
    }
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. If it doesn't make sense, that's fine to say as well.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your question isn't very clear

Comment: Whatever it is you're planning to do with this, there's almost certainly a better solution to your actual problem…

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an extra template parameter to the `make_foo` function, and add an extra template parameter to the original `foo` class (they would be `int`s), and choose a different value for each time the function is called. If you want it to increment automatically, the best thing I can think of is using `__LINE__`. Then you can `#define MAKE_FOO(targs, val) make_foo<targs, __LINE__>(val)`. Add more `targs` as necessary. Don't forget to wrap `foo` in an anonymous namespace if you really want each instance to be a separate class (if this is going to be in a header file).